# Pydantic 2 abstract method is always being called in subclass, instead of the subclass method

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class, python-decorators, pydantic-v2

During an upgrade from pydantic ~1 to v2 (2.5) the following is a regression experienced

have the following code:

```
class classproperty(object):

    def __init__(self, getter):
        print("init self is: " + self.__class__.__name__)
        print("init getter is: " + str(getter))

        if "function A._base_func" in str(getter):
            print("That is function A._base_func")
        self.getter = getter

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):

        print(self.getter)
        if instance is None:
            return self.getter
        return self.getter(instance)

class MappedClassBase(abc.ABC):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        print("in init subclass. class name: " + cls.__name__)
        print(cls._base_func)

    @classproperty
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _base_func(cls) -> str:
        return "in the default abstract method impl"

class A(BaseModel, MappedClassBase):

    @classproperty
    def _base_func(cls) -> str:
        return "In A func"

class B(A):
    stam: int = 3
```

what is the reason that in the **init_subclass** "cls._base_func" is always being called to abstract method and not to the method of the subclass

How can I resolve that and make the decorator getter calling the subclass "A" and not the parent class "MappedClassBase" abstract method

Expecting the decorator to set the getter as the function of the subclass, and return it in the **get**